# Topology of Worklight Server on a Websphere Liberty Profile

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty, topology

I'm trying to understand the topology of Worklight. Specifically how does a WL Server handles its applications.

If I understood correctly, a WL Server has a `<httpEndpoint>`. This means that a set of WL Applications will have their context root on that port. Right?

This means, If I want to put /worklightconsole on a custom port, I'll need a network installation instead of a standalone so that I can have a cluster of WL instances and each one will bind to a different port.

Did I understood this matter correctly? Then I can use a reverse proxy to needle my requests to the correct instance of WL Server.
Right?

Thanks in advance!

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/c_typical_topology_of_an_ibm_wor.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the httpEndpoint entry defines the http and https port and the WL applications have their context root on these ports.
If you have different Liberty Servers with the same WL runtime, be sure that the you share the same database and same schema.
After that you can use a Web Proxy to load balance the requests between the different Liberty servers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bruno! I guess I'll need more RAM on my machine to keep the worklight administration console out of my public network then.. :)

Comment: I have a doubt regarding this sharing of WL runtime. If I have two instances of WLP connected to the same runtime, both instances will be able to serve the same app and adapters right? What about a adapter that is a event source? Each instance will do work on a periodical basis? I was thinking about have a WL Server instance dedicated only to being a "backend" (load balancer would never point to him) so that end users would not be impacted by performance issues and if both WL instances do the same work, I'll have to handle doubled work and will not have no benefit for end users. Right?

Comment: Worklight runtimes must use session affinity. That means that the reverse proxy routes all the request to the same server after the first request. It means that when you start a session it will route to whatever server but all the following requests on the same session will be routed to the same server.

Comment: Yes. But I'm not talking about session affinity because the one that takes the action is the WL Server itself with the WL.Server.createEventSource functionality. For instance, for the example bellow, each WL Server would be sending push notifications?
 https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/configuring_a_polling_event_source_to_send_push_notifications?lang=en